# Existe o realloc() em C++?

Tags: c, c++, memória, alocação

O `realloc()` é exclusivo do C? Teria alguma função que seria igual em C++?

Comment: É do C mas não é exclusivo, funciona perfeitamente no C++. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/?kw=realloc

Comment: Então n teria problema de usar? Pelo fato de misturar C com C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, realloc é exclusivo de C. Não existem uma função igual pq o estilo de programação é diferente em C++. É possível utilizar realloc/malloc/free em C++, mas não é nem um pouco recomendável. Para programas simples pode até funcionar, mas com técnicas mais complicadas (polimorfismo, templates, metaprogramming, etc.) é quase garantido que vai dar algum tipo de undefined behavior. Exemplo:

```
//Estrutura em C
struct Cor {
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;
};
void inicializar_cor(Cor* c, unsigned char _r, unsigned char _g, unsigned char _b) {
  c->r = _r;
  c->g = _g;
  c->b = _b;
}

//Estrutura em C++
struct Cor {
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;

  Cor(unsigned char _r, unsigned char _g, unsigned char _b) 
    : r{_r}, g{_g}, b{_b} {}
};
```

Alocando uma variável cor de valor vermelho dinamicamente:

```
//C
Cor* cor = malloc(sizeof(Cor));
inicializar_cor(cor, 255, 0, 0);

//C++
Cor* cor = new Cor{255, 0, 0};
```

Para criar e inicializar uma variável Cor em C é mais complicado do que em C++. O fato de não existirem construtores introduz o método adicional inicializar_cor e isso acrescenta um ponto de fraqueza, pois caso o usuário coloque um ponteiro nulo ou esqueça de chamar inicializar_cor, a estrutura será inválida. Mas esse não é o único problema, pois as regras de inicialização em C são bastante diferentes das regras em C++.

```
struct CorAlfa {
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;
  unsigned char alfa;
};

//C
CorAlfa* cor = malloc(sizeof(Cor)); //Ok!

//C++
CorAlfa* cor = new Cor{255, 255, 255}; //Erro!
```

Supondo que decidi adicionar suporte a cores com opacidade ao meu programa, mas durante a implementação esqueci de atualizar minha rotina de alocação. Em C, malloc aloca Cor*, retorna um ponteiro void* e converte implicitamente para CorAlfa*, silenciosamente gerando um programa que vai dar problemas em execução pois CorAlfa é um struct de 4 bytes, enquanto Cor é um struct de somente 3 bytes. Em C++, isso é algo trivial que o compilador reconhece e mostra o erro.

Problemas que em C seriam resolvidos com realloc, tem outras alternativas em C++:

- Compor uma estrutura de dados baseada em [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [std::forward_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list), ou [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) para delegar o gerenciamento da alocação dinâmica (simples).
- Gerenciar a alocação dinâmica com [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (simples).
- Implementar rotinas com [move semantics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) para reutilizar memória e evitar cópias desnecessárias (intermediário).
- Implementar alocadores customizados (avançado). Assista essa [palestra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIb3L4vKZ7U) em inglês para uma introdução a essa técnica.

C++ tem uma série desses mecanismos de safe guard, que adicionam mais confiança aos programas. Com as últimas atualizações (C++17 e C++20) os compiladores estão ficando cada vez mais inteligentes e capazes de otimizar melhor essas estruturas de segurança, principalmente o GCC e o Clang. Atualmente, muito pouco é perdido em performance e às vezes códigos bastante complexos para um programa em C++ geram o mesmo assembly para o mesmo programa escrito em C, exceto que C++ proporciona um ambiente de programação mais seguro, com mais recursos e mais produtivo.

Comment: Nossa.. Mto obrigado pela explicação! Me ajudou mto!!

Answer (score 3):

Não é exclusivo do C, existe em C++ também, mas quase nunca deve ser usado. Pode existir alguns casos quando está criando uma estrutura e precisa lidar com gerenciamento de memória em nível mais baixo. Em C++ só se usar `new` e `delete`, e mesmo assim se algo já existente na biblioteca não resolve bem para você.

Então se não deve usar `malloc()` e `free()` em C++, porque faria sentido usar `realloc()`?

Se usá-lo está programando em C no C++, isso costuma ser errado, mas funciona.

Comment: Hmm ok! Estou familiarizado com o " new ". Obr!